# Floor function to float numbers

Tags: ruby, decimal, floor

I wrote a ruby code that rounds down a number as follows:

```
def round_down(number)
  number.to_s.split(/\./)[0].to_i
end
round_down(1.9)
```

Does somebody know a more rubystic way to achieve this?

Comment: Whenever you ask yourself something like this [look at the manual entry for the class in question](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Float.html). Usually there's a method that does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JavaScript's `Math.floor` function already exists in Ruby: `1.9.floor`

What you are doing in your code is actually something else, which also exists: `1.9.truncate`

They are the same for positive numbers, but for negative numbers `truncate` behaves like `ceil`:

- `floor` rounds down
- `ceil` rounds up
- `truncate` rounds towards zero

Answer (score 1):

You could use `BigDecimal#round` which has many different [rounding modes](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html#method-c-mode):

```
require 'bigdecimal'
def round_down(number)
  BigDecimal.new(number, 0).round(0, :down)
end

round_down(1.9)
#=> 1.0

round_down(-1.9)
#> -1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

ceil, round and truncate methods are available in ruby

```
[4] pry(main)> 1.9.round
=> 2
[10] pry(main)> 1.1.round
=> 1
[5] pry(main)> 1.9.ceil
=> 2
[9] pry(main)> 1.1.ceil
=> 2
[6] pry(main)> 1.9.truncate
=> 1
[8] pry(main)> 1.2.truncate
=> 1
```

Comment: @liya when I was typing answer, None had answered. In between I got busy with my works and then submitted the answer.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to reinvent the wheel:

```
1.9.divmod(1).first # => 1
-1.9.divmod(1).first # => -2
```